# Create list in android studio but constantly getting this error "Adapter View is abstract, cannot be initiated"

Tags: java, android

I want to create a list in Android Studio but constantly getting the error "Adapter View is abstract, cannot be initiated" on this line.

```
AdapterView arrayAdapter = new AdapterView (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, family );
```

How can I resolve it?

Code here:

```
package com.example.mylist;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView MyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyList);

        ArrayList family = new ArrayList();

        family.add("Abc");
        family.add("Def");
        family.add("Ghi");

        AdapterView arrayAdapter = new AdapterView (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, family );

        MyList.setAdapter((ListAdapter) arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try This*

```
    ArrayList<String> family = new ArrayList<String>();
    family.add("Abc");
    family.add("Def");
    family.add("Ghi");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,family );
    MyList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: So instead of "AdapterView", I should have written "ArrayAdapter<String>". Thanks, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Works as designed: that class AdapterView is declared **abstract**. It is **not** meant to be instantiated via `new()` directly.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html) for some guidance how to actually use that class!

And the usual advise to newbie Android programmers: learn a bit of java basics first. To understand what *abstract* really means is super basic stuff.